# При загрузке данных из JSON файла, файл неправильно декодируется

Tags: python, json, discord, decode

я делаю discord бота используя discord.py, но у меня возникает неправильное декодирование. Вот мой код:

```
async def shop(ctx):
    with open('saves.json', 'r+') as f:
        saves = json.load(f)
        emb = discord.Embed(title=f'Магазин {ctx.guild.name}', colour=discord.Color.purple())
        for i in range(len(saves["shop_items"])):
            item = saves["shop_items"][i]
            emb.add_field(name=item["name"], value=f'{item["description"]}.\n Стоимость: **{item["price"]} '
                                                   f'<:tyantherium:1049409159789031454>**.')
        await ctx.reply(embed=emb)
```

saves.json:

```
{
    "shop_items": [
        {
            "name": "Ядерная боеголовка",
            "price": 0,
            "description": "УСТРОЙТЕ БОМБЁЖКУ",
            "answer": "Кое где вырос большой ядерный гриб!",
            "role": null
        }
    ]
}
```

Вот что я получаю в ответ в discord:
[image: Магазин ℕ | OFFICIAL SERVER РЇРґРµСЂРЅР°СЏ Р±РѕРµРіРѕР»РѕРІРєР° РЈРЎРўР РћР™РўР• Р‘РћРњР‘РЃР–РљРЈ. Стоимость: 0 :tyantherium:.]

Помогите, пожалуйста, ломаю голову над этой ошибкой уже 3 день.

Comment: попробуйте для метода `open` добавить атрибут `encoding='utf-8'`

Comment: Спасибо, выручили!